# How can i create a list full of all tickers of companies in a specific industry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, finance, yahoo-finance, yfinance

How would I be able to iterate through the yfinance database and append all companies within specific industries into specific lists?

```
y = int(input("number of tickers:"))

def info(x):
    comp = yf.Ticker(x)
    print(comp.history(period="1d").head())
    print(comp.info['forwardPE'])
    print(comp.info['trailingPE'])
    print(comp.info['beta'])


for a in range(y):
    info(x=input("Enter ticker: "))
```

This is what I have so far, which works, and I was hoping to add something to allow me to compare companies within the same industry. Also, is there a list of possible commands that I can use? I've had varying success with ones I have found so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your info() function, instead of printing the company's information, you need to append the ticker symbol to the corresponding industry list.

```
import yfinance as yf

y = int(input("Number of tickers: "))
industry_lists = {}

def info(x, industry):
    comp = yf.Ticker(x)
    print(comp.history(period="1d").head())
    print(comp.info['forwardPE'])
    print(comp.info['trailingPE'])
    print(comp.info['beta'])
  
    if industry in industry_lists:
        industry_lists[industry].append(x)
    else:
        industry_lists[industry] = [x]

for a in range(y):
    ticker = input("Enter ticker: ")
    industry = input("Enter industry: ")
    info(x=ticker, industry=industry)

for industry, tickers in industry_lists.items():
    print(f"Industry: {industry}")
    print("Tickers:", tickers)
    print()
```

To compare companies within the same industry, you can access the industry lists in the industry_lists dictionary and perform any comparisonsneeded.